# How to create system restore point on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: restore

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a HP Z228 Microtower Workstation, and I installed Android Studio on it. Since there were so many components needed to be download and installed, I want to create a system restore point on it, just like those could be done on Windows 8.1. How to do it?

Comment: HP Z228 Microtower Workstation - Specifications is here:https://support.hp.com/si-en/document/c04638132#AbT1

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing to a Windows-like restore point is by using `Timeshift`. I use it to save snapshots to an external USB hard drive. Although it can, it's normally not used for backing up your /home directory, just system-level changes. Use `Backups` (Déjà Dup) for backing up /home files.

> Timeshift is a system restore utility which takes snapshots
>       of the system at regular intervals. These snapshots can be restored
>       at a later date to undo system changes. Creates incremental snapshots
>       using rsync or BTRFS snapshots using BTRFS tools.

More information at https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

Add the PPA and install with:

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install timeshift`

Comment: Didn't know timeshift was in the regular repos! I installed it from a ppa.

Comment: @OrganicMarble you're absolutely correct! Updated my answer to include more info. Thanks!

Comment: I found myself installing android studio myself. unfortunately it did filled the partion it was, and as I am still learning it caused a block of the filesystem. As the partition structure was not the best, and as I had backup data I decided to reinstall all together. It all went well till again due the particular laptop I do have( lenovo Legion Y520 with 1Tb hdd and 128 ssd integrated graphic cpu +  nvidia gtx 1050). Unfortunately I did not remembered that the 2 card could get in conflict. On top of that the update download the latest drives for nvidia, but not the one that played well with OS

Comment: I ended with login loop all together and once I read this is a common issue since many versions. The actual soclution , purge all drives for nvidia even did not worked for me, and I realized the apt-get command install the latest available drivers, without check if the right one for the card. I decided to deactivate nvidia card and stay with the Intel one, and reinstalled all together.So that make possible unstable system or worst crash(think about it in the middle of a project or a delivery patch where you can't say "my system crashed for last update sorry".

Comment: @CarmineTambascia I'm confused. What do your last two comments have to do with this answer?

Comment: Does Timeshift could be a solution in such case. If not considering that Linux world is the pioneer of solution such docker, does exist same projects, or could be an interesting one?

Comment: @ heynnema as it is not really a question but more a discussion of approach and if Timeshift could be useful in this matter "System restore point" for potential crash as in the case of drivers upgrade.

Comment: @CarmineTambascia I don't know. Your comments were way too long, and provided way too much history about your situation. And this is not really a discussion board. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema ok, well was to give a context. Thanks anyway. I will explore

Comment: This seems doing that, but the development stopped to 16.x though seems compatible with 18 and 19 https://sourceforge.net/projects/systemback/

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (and most Linux systems) don't have a "restore point" concept like Windows does because all components in Linux are simply files. Unless you specifically run a command as root (`sudo`) all your files are stored in your home directory (`~`) - in the case of Android Studio they are stored in the directories `~/Android` and `~/android-studio` and you can back those up files up like you would any other file, such as a creating a compressed archive.

If you're looking for a way to backup all the *packages* you have installed using `apt` you can do:

```
dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list
```

Then you can keep the `Packages.list` file and later "restore" it using:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y
```

However, it's likely that the only package you ever installed to use Android Studio was `openjdk-11-jdk` and **such a process is overkill**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default Backup tool that comes with Ubuntu (Déjà Dup). It will backup your entire home directory, allowing you to rollback etc. It is very easy to use.

In this article they explain how to set it up:
https://www.techjunkie.com/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-linux-distribution-with-deja-dup/

Comment: While providing links is useful, it would be _more_ helpful to the asker if you posted a summary of the steps involved on the link you posted as external links can go dead / be removed at any time. For more tips, see [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeshift

```
sudo apt install timeshift
```

[image: timeshift]

For creating a system restore point or snapshot just click on the `Create` button

For rolling back to the previous state, select the snapshot and click on the `Restore` button & follow the further procedure

If you want, you can configure your schedule snapshot too. Just click on `Settings -> Schedule`

> Despite GUI, you can use the timeshift from the command line too

Creating a Restore point

```
sudo timeshift --create --comments "A new backup" --tags D
```

Restoring snapshot

```
sudo timeshift --restore
```